# How To Make Log In system Using vb.net and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm using this code and every time I press the loginBTN where my code are nothing happens im done with connecting in the server which is SQL Server

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles loginbtn.Click
    Dim username As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim password1 As String

    Dim oleConn As New SqlConnection(main.conString)
    oleConn.Open()

    Try
        Dim login As String = "Select *from admin where username = '" & usernametxt.Text & "' AND password = '" & passwordtxt.Text & "' "

        Dim command As New SqlDataAdapter(login, oleConn)
        Dim command1 As New SqlCommand(login, oleConn)
        Dim reader1 As SqlDataReader = command1.ExecuteReader()

        If reader1.HasRows Then
            While reader1.Read
                username = reader1("username")
                password = reader1("password")

                password1 = passwordtxt.Text()

                If username = usernametxt.Text And password = password1 Then
                    main.Show()
                    Me.Hide()
                End If
            End While
        Else
            PictureBox1.Show()
            errorLabel.Show()
            Beep()
            'MsgBox("wrong password or username")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        oleConn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: A couple of improvements you could make: use executeScalar() & remove the need of the loop and use ADO.Net parameterisation to remove the login page to be a target of SQL injection hacking attacks: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx. Have you been able to step through the code in debug mode? Are any of the lines being executed in this event?

Comment: I would also look at storing an encrypted password in the database an send an encrypted password in the query. As it stands the query is sending a plain text password and the database is storing all passwords in plain text. Finally dependant on which SQL you are using - you should try not to use reserved words as fields names. PASSWORD is a reserved word in MS SQL... not sure about other flavours of SQL

Comment: Use a breakpoint to check execution process of the code. Use watch window to check variable values and post your experience. Is there any specific error ?